# category slug and page slug same

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have `movies` category name/slug and i have same page slug/name `movies`.

My category page: `sitename.com/movies/page/2,3,4` bla bla

My page URL: `sitename.com/movies/query`

If i enter first page on category don't see problem but if i going to next page (page/1,2,3) page is not work.

```
add_rewrite_rule('movies/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=movies&tag=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_tag('%tag%','([^&]+)');
```

this my page rewrite function code.

How can fix it?